# How to fix error of saving file Laravel using File facade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get the following error:

```
{"errors":"Method Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::create does not exist."}
```

Imports are:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

Code is:

```
$created = File::create(["path" => $path.$filename]);
```

Comment: Despite error it creates file in directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to save file uploading from a form, simply use [Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$path = Storage::putFile('path/avatars', $request->file('avatar'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you will look to an official laravel API, there is no such method ::create on File facade.

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html

What are you trying to achieve ?

If you want to create a new file use ::put method:

```
int|bool put(string $path, string $contents, bool $lock = false)
```

look at API link that I've provided. Or check official docs

Comment: I try to save file in local storage, what method to use instead?

Comment: use ::put method